# Addressable related confusion at runtime (for Unity games)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, sprite, sprite-sheet, assetbundle, addressables

Respected Seniors,

I need proper guidance for **Addressable**, please.
If someone wants to share his or her experiences, I would be very thankful for it. I am not able to understand after watching so many videos; I am so confused about them.

- I need to upload the different spritesheets (almost 5 to 10) with different labels (should I make a separate group for each spritesheet or place them in a single group, which will be a better way in terms of performance, etc)?
- And I am confused about the addressable cache and data.
  When something new is added to the server, I want spritesheets to download from the server only once and update on the user's device only when we update the data at server.
- The cache and data for addressable will be available until the user uninstall the application or this will be deleted in 150 days. (Someone told me this will delete automatically after 150 days.)

Please guide me about the settings and code. I have also done some stuff, but Addressable is a very confusing topic, so I am not sure if I am doing it correctly or not.

I am hoping for a positive response. Thank you for your precious time.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I have edited and now trying to ask the more appropriate question, so please guide me, if you are familiar with it. Thank you